# WPF : Custom DataGridRows with Custom style

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i have a DataGrid, i want to add each row of this DataGrid, one by one, then check the information in that Row, if something in it (lets call it cancel) is true, that row is colored black, otherwise its colored white.

i'd also want to know how the contents in that row can be modified, like set text of each cell in it, and then add it to the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill and modify a DataGrid you bind an ObservableCollection to the DataGrid's ItemSource Property. 
You can then modify the Collection as you like. For the layout you can use a Style.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Cancel}" Value="false">
                    <Setter  Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <!--
     ...
     -->
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don't have a list, I have a datatable, from a database